# What is the command to install `python-pil` and `x11-apps`

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, themes

I am trying to render [Yaru cursor theme](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/blob/master/icons/src/cursors/README.md). I have a few scripts. But it says

> to build and the render the cursor set you'll need `python-pil` and `x11-apps` installed.

I am not sure which commands to use to install them. Any help will be great.

I have 18.04 fully updated.

Comment: I am on 18.04. Which command should I use ? Python 2 or 3. I am not able to locate any command for installing x11-apps. Thanks.

Comment: I have x11-apps installed in 18.04 with `sudo apt install x11-apps`. If it says to install python-pil that's for Python 2. python3-pil is for Python 3.

Comment: You should try `apt search python | grep -i pil` (apt is your frontend to dpkg, your packagemanager. search is the search option, python is what you are looking for. grep will give you only the more relevant entrys). same with `apt search x11-apps` ... And when you know the names, just replace search with install -> `apt install [package name]`

Comment: Thank you. I will try.

Comment: @Melebius It's Yaru cursor theme modified by me, which I am trying to build.  https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/blob/master/icons/src/cursors/README.md

Comment: ]Possible duplicate of [How do I install pillow in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959504/how-do-i-install-pillow-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts) and [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Yaru repository](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru) is intended for Ubuntu, so the specification “`python-pil` and `x11-apps`” most likely refers directly to [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) names. To [install these packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu), simply run:

```
sudo apt install python-pil x11-apps
```

> Which command should I use? Python 2 or 3.

Since the package names are directly specified, you don’t have to choose yourself. [`python-pil`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-pil) is a [Python 2 package](https://askubuntu.com/a/959524/250300) and you can simply check that the [`render-cursors.py`](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/blob/master/icons/src/cursors/render-cursors.py) script is written in Python 2 as it starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```